# Reuse mask buy microwave??? Coronavirus

Tags: coronavirus, face-mask-respirator

Just a wild idea of mine, can I reuse ER mask if I'm blasting it in the microwave to kill coronavirus or anything else on it? Will this disinfect the mask if there is anything on it, this is so I'll be able to use it again...

Comment: Answered here https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/21593/why-arent-we-sterilizing-n95-masks/21755

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why aren't we sterilizing n95 masks?](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/21593/why-arent-we-sterilizing-n95-masks)